# Qual uma boa prática para o uso de ModelBinders no MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou querendo criar uma página usando as melhores práticas no ASP.NET MVC.

Fiquei em dúvida de qual seria a melhor prática para eu modelar minha página usando modelbinders para "bindar" meu objeto automaticamente. Neste caso, minha dúvida ficou nos relacionamentos entre as classes, veja por exemplo o meu cenário:

```
    public class Pessoa
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public Perfil Perfil { get; set; }
    }

    public class Perfil 
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
```

Na minha view, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
 @model Pessoa

 <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Pessoa.naturezaOcorrencia, Model.GetStatus())
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Perfil, ???????)
 </div>
```

Sendo assim, como eu terminaria de preencher o DropDownList. Ele não aceita uma lista direta do Entity por exemplo: `Perfil.All().ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso ficaria:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Perfil, new SelectList(SEU MODEL, "ID", "Nome"), "Selecione o Perfil")
```